# Configuring PHP development environment

Tags: windows, docker, phpstorm, hyper-v, socat

After a long time of using LAMP and WAMP, I've decided to try out Docker (buying new hard drives today, so why not?).

I've managed to create containers for my website and everything works fine.

Content is updated, database is saved to the folder (so kind of persistent), however, I've read that it is possible to automatically start the project containers using integration inside the PhpStorm.

And here are the problems:

1. I am using Windows 10 Professional with Hyper-V enabled
2. Docker running as a service
3. Docker in Windows using NPIPE (Named Pipes)
4. PhpStorm only works with `tcp://` `unix://` URI
5. Tried to use socat to map pipe to tcp and failed (either device is busy, or unable to send 'send' command, or any other error, you name it)
6. Tried to start the Docker daemon using the configuration file with hosts set to pipes and tcp - failed again (guess it is only works for Azure)

Can someone give me a link to the detailed configuration of the Docker on the Windows or should I just fallback to WAMP, because I REALLY don't want to install VMWare or VBox on my machine, neither I want to use out-of-the-box solutions for hosting local WAMP server (XAMPP, Open Server, Denver, etc), I just don't trust them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we have:

1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/docker.html

2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/docker-2.html

3) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Docker+Support+in+PhpStorm

4) https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-workshop - you can checkout `docker` branch. This project contains some examples/tutorials you can try right inside IDE

If that doesn't help at all - please attach/describe an error message you're getting in IDE.

Comment: Ástþór, thankyou for reply, i've made a video describing the error im getting https://youtu.be/AgaTeqhHaXw

Comment: please check that daemon is exposed on 2375 - this seems to be a new settings that is disabled by default after a recent Docker update: https://i.gyazo.com/be5c25e05988a8f191addd6b80d95fd7.png